# 950 XL Hard Reset - Can't Login to MS Account

Tags: lumia, reset, lumia-950-xl

I am trying to hard reset a 950xl, which has always, until now, been an easy process.

However, now when I get to the MS Account Sign-in screen during the phone hard reset process, my login always fails. Every time. It just returns me to the sign-in page and adds a captcha box to the screen - even when I reset the account password, using my PC, of course.

I try it on my PC to make sure I indeed know the password, and the login process works fine. I have checked the spelling and capitalization a thousand times.

It may be that my phone can't connect to Wifi - not sure.

So this is truly odd. Anyone seen this behavior before? Does anyone know to resolve it or what to check?

Anyone?